# Export several datasets toExcel() at a time

Tags: javascript, excel, datatable, export-to-excel, webix

I didn't find any mention of the possibility to export a data from several Webix data sources to the one Excel file.

Something like `webix.toExcel($$("table1"), $$("table2"));` isn't working (obviously) but perhaps there's any way to export multiple data?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Pre-snippet: http://webix.com/snippet/269edb58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to export excel file with multiple sheets. But you still can combine all data in one file like next

```
var dt = new webix.DataCollection({});
dt.parse($$("table1").serialize());
dt.parse($$("table2").serialize());
webix.toExcel(dt);
```